# How to create a "watchdog" for a python script running on a shared host (no ssh access or shell scripts)

Tags: python, server-side, remote-server, shared-hosting

My friends and I have written a simple [telegram bot](https://telegram.org/blog/bot-revolution) in python. The script is run on a remote shared host. The problem is that for some reason the script stops from time to time, and we want to have some sort of a mechanism to check whether it is running or not and restart it if necessary.

However, we don't have access to ssh, we can't run bash scripts and I couldn't find a way to install [supervisord](http://supervisord.org/). Is there a way to achieve the same result by using a different method?

P.S. I would appreciate it if you gave detailed a explanation as I'm a newbie hobbyist. However, I have no problem with researching and learning new things.

Comment: This question might be better suited for [SuperUser](http://superuser.com/) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com/) than StackOverflow.

Comment: @das-g Thanks for the input. I'll check them out.

Comment: @das-g I just checked out both superuser and serverfault, and I think this question doesn't really belong there. Stackoverflow might not be the ideal place for this question but it's better than those two websites

Answer (score 0):

You can have a small *supervisor* Python script whose only purpose is to start (and restart) your main application Python script. When your application crashes the *supervisor* takes care and restarts it.

Comment: How does the supervisor find out that my script has stopped? That's my main problem

Comment: It is able to recognize that your application has terminated. If it is still running but not responding you have to find another way.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what you're saying. How is it able to do that?